# Python の IDLE で保存ができない

Tags: windows, python-idle

Pythonで保存ができません。
IDLE の画面で save、save as をして名前をつけても保存コマンドが出来ないのです。
エラーメッセージも出ません。

何か理由があるのでしょうか。分からず10時間以上格闘しています。

**実行環境**
Python 3.8.5
Windows 10 (64bit)

Comment: 私の環境でも同様の現象が発生しています。保存するコードに日本語(文字列、コメント)が含まれているのが直接原因のようですが、まだ解決していません。

Comment: ありがとうございます、日本語の文字列をなくしてチャレンジします

Answer (score 1):

こちの環境でも「日本語を含むソースの保存ができない」現象が発生していましたが、バージョンは3.8.4でした。3.8.5にバージョンを上げると日本語を含むソースが保存できるようになりました。

質問された方の環境は`python3.8.5`とのことですので、原因は別かもしれません。
こちらのPythonの詳細なバージョンは以下です。

```
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

インストールしたファイルは以下です。
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/python-3.8.5-amd64.exe

Comment: ありがとうございます。ダウングレードして再チャレンジしてみます。　　どうやらPCの問題かもしれません。